# Opening a Lightning Community page with Lightning:tabset and Tabs

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-tab, lightning-tabfocused

I would like to place a Lightning:Tabset and Tab component on several pages of a Lightning Community and open each page with the Tabs. The reason is that the current standard Tabs component will not allow you to select a different page layout in the Content area of each tab. I got really close using the below component and JS controller. It opened each page but the tab for the page I was on was not highlighted (in focus).

Component:

```
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <div class="slds-m-around--large" style="height:10rem">
        <div class="slds-tabs_default">
            <ul class="slds-tabs_default__nav" role="tablist">
                <li aura:id="homeId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps slds-active" title="Home" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac" onclick="{!c.homeTab}" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-default-1" id="tab-default-1__item">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="whatsnewId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="What's New?" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-whatsnew" onclick="{!c.whatsnewTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-2" id="tab-default-2__item">What's New?</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="overviewId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="Overview" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-overview" onclick="{!c.overviewTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-3" id="tab-default-3__item">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="faqsId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="FAQs" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-faqs" onclick="{!c.faqsTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-4" id="tab-default-4__item">FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="trainingId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="Training" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-training" onclick="{!c.trainingTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-5" id="tab-default-5__item">Training</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="supportId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="Support" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-support" onclick="{!c.supportTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-6" id="tab-default-6__item">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li aura:id="beyondId" class="slds-tabs--default__item slds-text-title--caps" title="Beyond AC" role="presentation">
                    <a class="slds-tabs_default__link" href="/s/ask-ac-beyondac" onclick="{!c.beyondTab}" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-default-7" id="tab-default-7__item">Beyond AC</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div aura:id="homeTabDataId" id="tab-default-1" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-1__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="whatsnewTabDataId" id="tab-default-2" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-2__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="overviewTabDataId" id="tab-default-3" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-3__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="faqsTabDataId" id="tab-default-4" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-4__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="trainingTabDataId" id="tab-default-5" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-5__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="supportTabDataId" id="tab-default-6" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-6__item">
            </div>
            <div aura:id="beyondTabDataId" id="tab-default-7" class="slds-tabs_default__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-default-7__item">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

and JS

```
({

homeTab: function(component, event, helper) {

    var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
    var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

    var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
    var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

    var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
    var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

    var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
    var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

    var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
    var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

    var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
    var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

    var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
    var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

    //show and Active home tab
    $A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.addClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-hide');

    // Hide and deactivate others tab
    $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');
},
whatsnewTab: function(component, event, helper) {

    var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
    var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

    var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
    var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

    var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
    var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

    var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
    var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

    var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
    var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

    var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
    var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

    var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
    var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

    //show and Active whatsnew tab
    $A.util.addClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.addClass(TabTwodata, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabTwodata, 'slds-hide');

    // Hide and deactivate others tab
    $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');

},
overviewTab: function(component, event, helper) {

    var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
    var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

    var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
    var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

    var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
    var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

    var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
    var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

    var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
    var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

    var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
    var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

    var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
    var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

    //show and Active overview tab
    $A.util.addClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.addClass(TabThreedata, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabThreedata, 'slds-hide');

    // Hide and deactivate others tab
    $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');

},
faqsTab: function(component, event, helper) {

    var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
    var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

    var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
    var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

    var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
    var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

    var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
    var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

    var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
    var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

    var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
    var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

    var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
    var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

    //show and Active faqs tab
    $A.util.addClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.addClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-hide');

    // Hide and deactivate others tab
    $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

    $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
    $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
    $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');
},
trainingTab: function(component, event, helper) {

        var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
        var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

        var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
        var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

        var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
        var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

        var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
        var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

        var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
        var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

        var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
        var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

        var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
        var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

        //show and Active training tab
        $A.util.addClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFivedata, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFivedata, 'slds-hide');

        // Hide and deactivate others tab
        $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');
},
supportTab: function(component, event, helper) {

        var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
        var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

        var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
        var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

        var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
        var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

        var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
        var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

        var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
        var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

        var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
        var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

        var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
        var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

        //show and Active support tab
        $A.util.addClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSixdata, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSixdata, 'slds-hide');

        // Hide and deactivate others tab
        $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSevenData, 'slds-hide');
},
beyondTab: function(component, event, helper) {

        var tab1 = component.find('homeId');
        var TabOnedata = component.find('homeTabDataId');

        var tab2 = component.find('whatsnewId');
        var TabTwoData = component.find('whatsnewTabDataId');

        var tab3 = component.find('overviewId');
        var TabThreeData = component.find('overviewTabDataId');

        var tab4 = component.find('faqsId');
        var TabFourData = component.find('faqsTabDataId');

        var tab5 = component.find('trainingId');
        var TabFiveData = component.find('trainingTabDataId');

        var tab6 = component.find('supportId');
        var TabSixData = component.find('supportTabDataId');

        var tab7 = component.find('beyondId');
        var TabSevenData = component.find('beyondTabDataId');

        //show and Active beyond tab
        $A.util.addClass(tab7, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSevendata, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSevendata, 'slds-hide');

        // Hide and deactivate others tab
        $A.util.removeClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabOneData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabOneData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab2, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabTwoData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab3, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabThreeData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab4, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFourData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFourData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab5, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabFiveData, 'slds-hide');

        $A.util.removeClass(tab6, 'slds-active');
        $A.util.removeClass(TabSixData, 'slds-show');
        $A.util.addClass(TabSixData, 'slds-hide');

},
```

})

Again this opened the correct page when selecteing the tab but did not highlight the specific tab corresponding to the page. I then tried the below code which did the opposite. It highlighted each tab selected but I could not figure out how to open the page with each tab.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<div class="demo-only" style="height:10rem">
    <lightning:tabset>
        <lightning:tab label="Home" onactive="{!c.loadHomeTab}" id="homeId">
        </lightning:tab>                                                                                                    
        <lightning:tab label="Whats New?" onactive="{!c.loadWhatsNewTab}" id="whatsnewId">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Overview" onactive="{!c.loadOverviewTab}" id="overviewId">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="FAQ's" onactive="{!c.loadFAQsTab}" id="faqsId">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Training" onactive="{!c.loadTrainingTab}" id="trainingId">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Support" onactive="{!c.loadSupportTab}" id="supportId">
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Beyond AC" onactive="{!c.loadBeyondTab}" id="beyondId">
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</div>
```

JS:

```
({
loadHomeTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac'
},
loadWhatsNewTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-whatsnew'
},
loadOverviewTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-overview'
},
loadFAQsTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-faqs'
},
loadTrainingTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-training'
},
loadSupportTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-support'
},
loadBeyondTab : function(component, event, helper) {
// do whatever you want
    url:'/s/ask-ac-beyondac'
},
selectedTab : function(component, event, helper) { 
component.find("tabSet").set("v.selectedTabId", tabId);
},
```

})

How do I acheive what I want to do; place a Lightning Tab Component in the Content Header of 7 pages and open each page with the tab and so the tab corresponding to the tab is highlighted? Thanks

Comment: For the first way, where you use SLDS styling and not the built-in lightning component, [the documentation here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tabs/#Expected-Markup) says "In order to achieve the focus state styling, apply .slds-has-focus to the parent li". Have you tried adding that class?

Comment: To be honest I am a novice and do not know how to achieve that with the existing SLDS styling code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For example, when you are selecting the home page tab you are calling `$A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-active');
 $A.util.addClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-show');
 $A.util.removeClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-hide');` so you could add `$A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-has-focus');` which adds the class to the `li` element which has the ID of 'homeId'

Comment: I have tried adding `$A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-has-focus');` under `$A.util.addClass(tab1, 'slds-active'); $A.util.addClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-show'); $A.util.removeClass(TabOnedata, 'slds-hide');` and then repeated for each Function but nada.